# What is the name of a liquid coupler between a wet/dry vac and a hose?

Tags: vacuum

The contraption you see below closes a wet/dry vac's liquid exit. I'd like to replace it with "something" that connects to a water hose.

[image: contraption]

What would that "something" be called?

I would attach a valve to the other end of the water hose. If such a thing (hose + valve + thing) is readily available, it would be even better.

I can go to my hardware store and ask them, but I know from experience that they'll make me walk back and forth between gardening and plumbing until I can just identify what I'm looking for. Hence I'd much rather ask here, and perhaps just order online.

**Update**

With the keywords "drain hose adapter" I have now identified what would be ideal.

I'm looking for something exactly like this

[image: pump]

but without the pump. Do they make it or do I have to DIY?

Comment: Check the inner diameter of the cap - I think it looks about 2 1/2 inches.  You'll want plumbing - a 2 1/2" to 3/4" conversion but I don't think you'll find one unless you get multiple parts.

I guess the idea is to push the liquid out the hose instead of having to lift / dump it by hand?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo Exactly! I'm a puzzled what I'm looking for doesn't come with every shop vac that takes liquids. If I raise the shopvac just a bit off the ground, it'll be easy to drain what's in it by gravity. Good guess too: it is indeed 2 1/2".

Comment: You do understand it won't drain while the vac is running, yes?

Comment: @Harper Thanks. lol... there was a day when I was clueless about how these things work, but I now have a grasp that they're based on the "suction principle", or whatever the formal name for this is.

Comment: The point of the pump is that it will flow while the vac is *on*. Gravity won't do that (unless you can give the hose 30' of head.)  You'll want a check valve in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look for a [Drain Adapter Kit for Garden Hoses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WF31C1G). It may vary [by brand](http://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-Hose-to-Drain-Adapter-Accessory-for-RIDGID-Wet-Dry-Vacs-VT2519/202441732?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CBase&gclid=COPKp8js7dQCFcS1wAodb6UKmw&gclsrc=aw.ds).